# flask run vs. python

Tags: python, flask

I'm having difficulty getting my flask app to run by using the "python" method. I have no problems using

```
export FLASK_APP=microblog.py
flask run
```

but attempting to use

```
python microblog.py
```

will result in the following error

```
ImportError: No module named 'app'
```

where my microblog.py file looks like this:

```
from app import app, db
from app.models import User

@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return {'db': db, 'User': User}
```

and my `__init__.py` file looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

from flask_login import LoginManager


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'

from app import routes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The folder these files reside in is called 'app'. I've tried putting the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In the microblog.py file as well, which was also unsuccessful.

I also have folders for templates/static/etc. and a routes file where I run all my `@app.route()` commands

Again, everything works fine when I run "flask run" in terminal, it just breaks down when I try using "python microblog.py". I'm trying to launch the app on AWS and just about every tutorial requires the applications to be called using the "python" method. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have a file named `app.py` with `__init__.py` in same folder?

Comment: @Abe I have `microblog.py` and `__init__.py` in the same folder, yes. They're both located in the app folder.

Answer (score 2):

**[Solved]**

I had my directories mixed up. I pulled `microblog.py` back outside of the `app` folder and was able to run `python microblog.py` with no issues and without having to edit anything.

In hindsight, I probably should have posted the file structure of everything right in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

In this line `from app import app, db` you're trying to import a module called `app.app`, but it apparently does not exists in your project source.

Try to create a file named `app.py` inside `app/` path, copy and paste all content of `__init__.py` file inside of it.

Your `__init__.py` must be blank. It's just indicate that your path `app/` is a importable module.

[See this article.](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-is-init-py-used-for.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've done what you suggested, and while I could get the program to run, flask never provided me with an ip to access everything at the end (probably more tinkering required on my end to use the method you've suggested). I guess a better question to ask with my previous `__init__.py` file would be, why can `flask run` recognize `app` and display the correct information, but `python microblog.py` doesn't?

Comment: When you run using `python`, there is no server to be up, the file will be copiled and no instructions to start a server was given, while you're using `flask`, it runs a server to manage your requests.
This happens because `app.run()` isn't inside `microblog.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it worked for me on windows.

```
$env:FLASK_APP="hello.py"

flask run
```

That's it